# It is possible to log the parameters in pentaho PDI system

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation that run every night with a certain value of the parameters.

Is it possible to setup the logging so that the value of the parameters is written in the log ?

For you info, I have about a hundred transformations running on different cycles and a workaround like "Get variable" or a "User Defined Java Class" or even a DIY Plugging should be easy to add, and to automatize in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to log it yourself. Just use the get variables step which attaches the parms to the stream.

[image]

Comment: I thought about it, but this does not log them, just include in the stream. Also I should know the variable names, which means to edit all the transforms. [See my edit of the question]